# upload images with filepond and vue 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, filepond

I´m trying to upload image with `filepond` library. Mi problem it´s that `return 419 error`

to build my component in vue, i´m trying with this code:

```
<file-pond
        name="back_dni"
        ref="pond"
        class-name="my-pond"
        label-idle="DNI trasero"
        allow-multiple="false"
        accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
        v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
        server="/commercial/uploadDocuments" 
    />
```

In my script, i have example that it´s write in documentation:

***all import to create `Filepond`
.....***

```
// Create FilePond component
    const FilePond = vueFilePond(FilePondPluginImagePreview,FilePondPluginFileValidateType);

    setOptions({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        server: {
            process: {
            url: '/commercial/uploadDocuments',
            method: 'POST',
            withCredentials: false,
            onload: (response) => response.key,
            onerror: (response) => response.data,
            ondata: (formData) => {
                formData.append('Hello', 'World');
                return formData;
            },
        },
            revert: './revert',
            restore: './restore/',
            load: './load/',
            fetch: './fetch/',
        }
    });

    export default {
        name: 'uploadDniBack',
        data: function () {
            return { 
                myFiles: [] 
            };
        },
        
        methods: {
            handleFilePondInit: function () {
                // example of instance method call on pond reference
                this.$refs.pond.getFiles();
            },
        },
        components: {
            FilePond,
        },
    };
```

I´m sending headers with token, but i don´t know if i can send this data so.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like a problem with your csrf token

> HTTP response status code 419 Page Expired is an unofficial client error that is Laravel-specific and returned by the server to indicate that the Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) validation has failed.
> Source: [https://http.dev/419#:~:text=HTTP%20response%20status%20code%20419,(CSRF)%20validation%20has%20failed](https://http.dev/419#:%7E:text=HTTP%20response%20status%20code%20419,(CSRF)%20validation%20has%20failed).

Change `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` by `document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content` this works for me.

Comment: thanks for your response. But i change all my logic to build my solution. Your response, not resolve my problem i tryed with this code in first place but not run. Thanks